# Вектор указателей, инкапсулированный внутрь класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, vector

У меня есть некий класс `A`:

```
class A
{
private:
    int val = 0;
public:
    A() = default;
};
```

И класс `GroupeA`, который хранит вектор указателей на тип `A`:

```
class GroupeA
{
public:
    std::vector<A*> vec;
};
```

Нужно ли мне описывать в классе `GroupeA` конструктор копирования, перемещения, перегружать оператор присваивания и описывать деструктор?

Большое спасибо.

Comment: Это вам решать нужно или нет. Если вас устраивают  варианты по умолчанию, то не нужно писать, но ваш  класс А в таком виде бесполезный

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, согласен :) Забыл добавить, что у меня есть возможность добавлять в вектор новые элементы.

Comment: Если вектор *владеет* указуемыми элементами, то нужно. Если *не владеет* - то не нужно. А уж владеет или нет - это известно только вам. Но лучше было бы описавать семантику владения через соответствующий умный указатель и не писать никаких дополнительных методов.